# Custom Metal CIKernel return fixed color produces different color

Tags: ios, image-processing, metal, ciimage, cikernel

I hava a custom CIKernel by Metal, I found a weird thing that shader return a fixed color, but screen display is different! I use break point to check produced CIImage object, is really different color.

there is my code

```
float4 test(sample_t s) {
    return float4(16 / 255.0, 16 / 255.0, 16 / 255.0, 1);
}
```

and this is result in breakpoint.

[image]

I want a (16,16,16) color, but it produced a (62,62,62) color.

I tried many times and got this graph, (x axis is input value(shader return), y axis is result)

[image]

it looks like there is a gamma correction? how to fix this? anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is most likely gamma correction.

Core Image uses a linear (not gamma-compressed) sRGB working color space, i.e. all the color values you read and write in your kernel are interpreted as linear, un-corrected light values. 
However, most render destinations have a non-linear color space (like sRGB or Display P3), so gamma compression is happening during rendering, which changes how pixel values are stored (but not displayed).

If you want to disable gamma correction for your output, you need to specify a linear output color space, like `linearSRGB` or `extendedLinearDisplayP3`.

Comment: where should I specify this color space? CISampler ?

Comment: I am developing a tone curve function, I found the final color mapped by curve is different from Photoshop's result, I think my curve is right, and I want to figure out what makes different, and found this. example, my curve turn 100 to 16, so some color in kernel sampled may be 100, and then should output 16, right? but the final color is 64, the whole image's color is not my want.

Comment: How do you render the CIImage? Almost all render APIs of `CIContext` have a `colorSpace` parameter. Try passing a linear color space there.

Comment: @FrankRupprecht If we set `workingColorSpace` to `NSNull()`, do we get gamma corrected values or linear values in the kernel?

Comment: @DeepakSharma You should get the same gamma correction (or lack thereof) as the input image. Core Image won't do any color conversion when you set `workingColorSpace` to `NSNull()`.